# SWIFT - How to change UIAlertController message after showing it

Tags: ios, swift, alert, uialertcontroller

I would like to change the UIAlertController's message after it is created.
Inside the alert I would like to show the status of download.

```
@IBAction func dbWillSync(sender: AnyObject) {
    alert = UIAlertController(title: "SYNC",
        message: "0%",
        preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let dismissHandler = {
        (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "STOP DOWNLOAD",
        style: .Cancel,
        handler: dismissHandler))

    presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    download();
}

func download(){
    for i in 1...100{
        alert.message="\(i) %"
        sleep(1)
    }
}
```

what is wrong ?

Thanks

***** EDIT *********

I do not know if it's the best solution:

```
let thread = NSThread(target:self, selector:"download", object:nil)
thread.start()
```

.. but it works!

Improvements are welcome!

Comment: Probably easiest to subclass UIAlertViewController, and add your progress view to it's main view.

Comment: It's not about the progress view, it's about the screen not updating until the download function terminates.

Comment: @ottorottok Your solution definitely works and is marginally appropriate.  There are other, perhaps better ways of putting the long-running operation (`download` in this case) on a background thread.  In this specific instance, it looks like `NSTimer` other possibilities are `GCD` and/or `NSOperation`  One thing to note is that anything that manipulates the UI should be done on the main thread, not on a background thread, so you should wrap that line in `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iOS, graphics actions don't happen in real time.  The alert is not yet put on the screen when you call your download method.  All the graphics happen after you exit your methods and return to the system main loop.  Thus when your download method is running, the alert isn't even displayed.  You have to update your alert message from the download itself.

Comment: They do absolutely happen in real time. It's just that nothing in terms of UI happens in real time when you're blocking the UI thread by sleeping.

Comment: I think by "real time" he means that the rendering doesn't actually happen when it looks like it should.  In this case, somebody unfamiliar with the process would expect the screen to update during the call to `presentViewController`  Instead, it doesn't happen until the bottom of the event loop, after all of this code (and in this case the 100 second long "download" call)  In far more definitive terms, nothing in iOS user land happens in "real time" which is a very specific term when one speaks of operating system performance.  Either way, the statement is true.

Comment: David's correct - If you step through your code, you won't see your viewController appear after you step through presentViewController.  It only appears after you've executed your method and fallen out to the system loop. If he removed the sleep() calls, he still wouldn't see the alert updating - it would have already been updated by the time the system displayed the view.

Answer (score 1):

### You can use this code its works!!**

```
 BG {
        self.UI {
            self.alertController.message = "update message"
        }
    }


.....


extension UIViewController {
func BG(_ block: @escaping ()->Void) {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async(execute: block)
    }
    
    func UI(_ block: @escaping ()->Void) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: block)
    }
}
```